# Dropdown for selectInput() is being masked by surrounding div

Tags: r, shiny

I have created below Shiny template to demonstrate the issue that I am facing to fully display `selectInput()`

```
library(shiny)


ui = shinyUI(       
        fluidPage(
            div(
                div(style = "margin-top: 110px;",                   
                wellPanel(
                        column(12, style = "background-color:WhiteSmoke; height:123px; margin: 0; padding: 0;", 
                            splitLayout(cellWidths =  c('60%', '30%'),
                                div(id = 'bb', style = "background-color: #e8e8e8; border-radius: 5px; padding: 20px 0px 10px 20px;", 
                                    splitLayout(cellWidths =  c('55%', '40%'),  
                                        div(id = 'aa', style = "z-index: 20000;", 
                                            selectInput(inputId = "Pick", label = "Chose", choices = c('A', 'B', 'C'), 
                                                                                selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE, size = NULL, width = 300))

                                    ))))


                    )
            )                   
    )))

server = function(input, output, session) {
    }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

As you see when I click on the drop down for `selectInput()`, entire element is not getting displayed, it is being masked by surrounding `div`.

Any idea how to resolve this problem would be highly appreciated. I tried with adjusting z-index, however could not succeed.

Thanks,

Comment: The issue is with the `splitLayouts`. If you comment those out you get the normal drop down for `selectInput()`. Do you need those? If you are trying to layout elements horizontally, you could use other methods.

Comment: I see that. Thanks. removed splitLayouts and its working fine now.

Comment: I put my comment as answer to consider the question "complete"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To consider the question "complete", you could remove the `splitLayouts` as I mentioned in my comment:

```
library(shiny)


ui = shinyUI(       
        fluidPage(
            div(
                div(style = "margin-top: 110px;",                   
                wellPanel(
                        column(12, style = "background-color:WhiteSmoke; height:123px; margin: 0; padding: 0;", 
                                div(id = 'bb', style = "background-color: #e8e8e8; border-radius: 5px; padding: 20px 0px 10px 20px;",   
                                        div(id = 'aa', style = "z-index: 20000;", 
                                            selectInput(inputId = "Pick", label = "Chose", choices = c('A', 'B', 'C'), 
                                                                                selected = NULL, multiple = FALSE, selectize = TRUE, size = NULL, width = 300))

                                    ))


                    )
            )                   
    )))

server = function(input, output, session) {
    }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: What if we need to use `splitLayout`? `splitLayout` is helpful to quickly spread out a lot of input boxes in one row. So why remove it?